# iphone - do an action while a button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button

Say for example i have two volume buttons ( + and - )

How can I implement something such as when holding the + button, it will raise up the volume incrementally at an interval? (I'm only interested in doing an action at an interval while the button is being pressed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a timer for this. Start the timer when the touch starts. If the timer expires, increase or decrease the volume and restart the timer. When the touch ends, cancel the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two button one for - and other for + ,

you could store the interval information in the tag field of your button

**Installing the interval value in your button tag property.**

```
myPulseButton.tag = 10;
myMinusButton.tag = 10;
```

**Adding action with your button.**

```
[myPulseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

[myMinusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Implement the buttonEvent method like below.**

```
-(void) buttonEvent:(id) sender
{
    UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*) sender;
    if(myButton == myPulseButton)
    {
      [self increaseVolume:myPulseButton.tag];
    }
    else if(myButton == myMinusButton)
    { 
      [self decreaseVolume:myMinusButton.tag];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the button...

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self  action:@selector(increase)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [view addSubview:button];
```

then write the method for buttton press.

```
-(void)increase
{
//increase the volume here
}
```

if it is not the solution you want means add the comment...